# Manually setting environment variables for Metasploit

Tags: shell, freebsd, ruby, metasploit

How do I set manually environment variables for Metasploit, when I execute `db_driver` I get this message:

```
[*] No Active Driver
[*]        Available: 

[*]     DB Support: Enable the postgresql driver with the following command:
[*]                   * This requires libpq-dev and a build environment
[*]                 $ gem install postgres
[*]                 $ gem install pg # is an alternative that may work
```

After googling, I find that Metasploit set some environment variables, and with that can load the installed drivers, but to me it's looks like Metasploit does not set environment variables.

Comment: Did the commands the error message told you to run not work or why do you want to set environment variables?

Comment: Setting environment variables help metasploit to load inatalled databases drivers correctly, see this [mail](http://seclists.org/metasploit/2011/q2/100).

Comment: Where did you run `msfconsole`? Is it `/pentest/exploits/framework3/msfconsole`?